# Determining Purpose of operator[] Usage

Tags: c++, class, methods, operators, operator-overloading

Let's say I have something like the following method in my container class:

```
Datatype& operator[](const unsigned int Index) // I know this should use size_t instead.
{
    return *(BasePointer + Index); // Where BasePointer is the start of the array.
}
```

I'd like to implement some sort of bounds-checking for the `MyInstance[Index] = Value` usage so the container resizes automatically if the user tries to change a value outside its range.  However, I want something else to happen if the user tries to *access* a value outside the container's range, e.g. `MyVariable = MyInstance[Index]`.  How can I detect how `operator[]` is being used?

Comment: You mean (for example) throw an exception for going out of bounds?

Comment: Maxpm: You can't. `operator[]` doesn't know what's being done with its result.

Comment: @Tomalak: That's most certainly wrong.

Comment: @sbi: Care to provide a longer explanation? I agree (in what I understood from @Tomalak's comment): When the compiler sees the call to the `operator[]` and resolves the call, it does not consider what the operator is being used for, only the types of the argument. Nor does it pass information into the operator[] about the context of the call. How is "`operator[]` doesn't know what's being done with its result" *most certainly wrong*?

Comment: @sbi: By all means elaborate. How do you suggest `operator[]` knows the context of what will happen to the result that it returns after it has been returned?

Comment: @Tomalak, @David: I have learned to never say "there's no way in C++", but only "I don't know any way to do this". When I wrote my reply to Tomalak, I thought of the proxy idea (which Konrad had written up faster than I could). I learned that more than ten years ago and am now surprised that it took so long for someone to post it.

Comment: @sbi: It's a fact that the function `operator[]` does not know what's being done with its result. *"That's most certainly wrong"* is a bizarre thing to say to it.

Comment: @sbi: I know about the proxy object approach, not for 10 years, but it is not something new. I guess I read the question formally: "How can I determine the purpose of operator[] use?" rather than, "I need to perform different operations when operator[] is used for a/b". To me the answer is still "no, you can't do it, even if there are workarounds"

Comment: @David: You can detect how `operator[]` is used by having it return a proxy and delegate the detection to that proxy. I suppose we're not bickering about how questions (and answers) are phrased here, are we? The intention was clear, and there was a way to do it. (And I would have assumed you know the technique. That doesn't change, however, that it took four answers and 15mins until someone posted it.)

Comment: @Tomalak: `<sigh/>` I was referring to what you started your comment with: _"You can't."_ I took that as your premise and it is, IMO, wrong. Of course you can't do it with `operator[]` alone. But there's no reason the operator can't delegate the work. (The all-time favorite _Programmer's All-Purpose Cure_: _Add another level of indirection._)

Comment: @sbi: Aha! Please be clearer next time as to which part of a comment you disagree with. Indeed, "you can't" is a bit broad; I probably ought to have said "`operator[]` can't".

Comment: @Tomalak: You said _"You can't", period_ (followed by an explanation why). If there's a way to do what the OP wants to do,  _"You're wrong"_ IMO is a very reasonable answer to that. If _"You can't", period_, is not what you wanted to do, then _you_, not me, should strive to express yourself more clearly. Besides, I think I have provided a way to express in reasonably clear English how the operator _can_ distinguish (by delegating the work).

Comment: One last thing: I like to think that, were the places swapped and you had told me I was wrong, I wouldn't have gotten _curious_ instead of _defensive_ as you did. But I am now really tired of this bickering about phrasing and will herewith remove myself from it.

Comment: @sbi: Please see my previous comment where I acknowledge this. Jees.

Comment: @sbi: You're just condescending. I don't know where this "defensive" nonsense comes from. I hereby remove myself from *any* future conversation with you.

Comment: @Tom @sbi Ladies, please.  ;)

Comment: @Maxpm: It's over; no need to add to it.

Comment: @sbi, in what affects me, my last comment was just trying to explain why I had added that comment, not trying to insist in it's correctness after it is clear that we were actually discussing different things, my superficial interpretation of the question (I don't usually have as much time as I'd like to read carefully) against your interpretation of the real intent of the question. Again, I do accept that I make mistakes, this won't be the first nor the last. I hope this has not been offensive in any way, as that was not my intention. If it was, apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sketch:

return a proxy object instead of the actual data entry. The proxy object then defines `operator =` to handle the assignment case, and an implicit conversion operator for the reading-out case.

```
template <typename T>
class AccessorProxy {
  friend class Container<T>;
public:
    AccessorProxy(Container<T>& data, unsigned index)
        : data(data), index(index) { }
    void operator =(T const& new_value) {
        // Expand array.
    }
    operator const T&() const {
        // Do bounds check.
        return *(data.inner_array + index);
    }
private:
    AccessorProxy(const AccessorProxy& rhs)
     : data(rhs.data), index(rhs.index) {}
    AccessorProxy& operator=(const AccessorProxy&);
    Container<T>& data;
    unsigned index;
};

template <typename T>
class ConstAccessorProxy {
  friend class Container<T>;
public:
    ConstAccessorProxy(const Container<T>& data, unsigned index)
        : data(data), index(index) { }
    operator const T&() const {
        // Do bounds check.
        return *(data.inner_array + index);
    }
private:
    ConstAccessorProxy(const ConstAccessorProxy& rhs)
     : data(rhs.data), index(rhs.index) {}
    ConstAccessorProxy& operator=(const ConstAccessorProxy&);
    const Container<T>& data;
    unsigned index;
};

AccessorProxy<Datatype> operator[](const unsigned int Index)
{
    return AccessorProxy<Datatype>(*this, Index);
}
ConstAccessorProxy<Datatype> operator[] const (const unsigned int Index)
{
    return ConstAccessorProxy<Datatype>(*this, Index);
}
```

The accessor classes will likely need to be be friends of the container class.

Finding ways to avoid the code duplication is left as an exercise to the reader. `:)`

Comment: Damn, I was still writing mine! `:)`

Comment: You might want to make this `operator const T&()`, no? And this one cannot be instantiated with a `const` container.

Comment: +1 I forgot about this.  deleting mine.  point of reference:  `std::auto_ptr` does something similar.

Comment: @sbi: Correct on both counts. This is why I wrote “sketch”. I’m actually somewhat *very* busy right now and have no business writing Stack Overflow answers (oh yes, but answer sketches are *completely* fine :D). Feel free to write a production-ready code ;-) … I’ll most definitely upvote it.

Comment: @Konrad: Did so. I hope you're Ok with it.

Comment: @sbi: now I can’t upvote. And a few points: the code won’t compile since `AccessorProxy` needs an accessible copy constructor (just for correctness, it will never be called because of NRVO/copy elision). Furthermore, the default copycon won’t work since the object contains a reference. Furthermore, the code probably also needs an `operator T&` (without the `const`) To make the assignment `T& x = c[0]` legal.

Comment: @Konrad: Ok, re #1: IMO the cctor shouldn't be public, but the container needs to be a friend in order to invoke it. Re #2: The default cctor would work (not the asignment op, though), but making it private unfortunately requires us to implement it explicitly. Re #3: That's true. I'll fix it - and wait for more errors to trickle in. `<sigh/>` I shouldn't have taken this up.

Comment: @Konrad: Re #3: I take that back. This would bring us back right to the "solution" with overloading `operator[]` based on `const`: There's no way to distinguish between these two conversion operators because there's now way to tell the compiler which of the implicit it should chose.

Comment: @sbi re #3: there doesn’t have to be. The *container* isn’t constant here, the object is. The semantics of the function are the same in both cases. The compiler will choose the correct conversion based on the type of the object that we assign to.

Comment: @Konrad: I must be missing something. `operator T&()` would be akin to `operator=(const T&)`, whereas `operator const T&() const` has a completely different semantic. If I have a non-`const` accessor (and that's what I get if I invoke `operator[]()`), it seems to me the compiler would always chose `operator T&()`, and never `operator const T&() const`. So what am I missing?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean `T& r = c[idx]` can't be supported by this? Bah. I remember that I really liked this idea when I learned about it, but in the last decade I must have forgotten what's wrong with it. (The fact that I don't have a single piece of working code doing this should have given me a clue, really...)

Comment: Hmm.  If `AccessorProxy` has both `operator T&() const` and `operator const T&() const`, are there any situations where C++ would undesirably call the former when not needed?  (Though I still might prefer documenting the container as "`c[i]` will only auto-extend the container when to the left of an equal sign or when used in `c[i].lvalue()`", to prevent accidental expands.)

Comment: On `AccessorProxy` copy constructor: That's why I used a private nested class with public copy constructor.  This protects incorrect usage of the proxy type from Murphy, though not from Machiavelli.  (There's template argument deduction, and in C++0x `auto` and `decltype`.)  Also, the copy assignment operator for the proxy should be public and should assign one element of the container, to support `c[i] = c[j]`.

Comment: @aschepler: Re the cctor: A public cctor of a private type can be invoked by users, though. For example, if that type is used as a template argument.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dummy class type to represent expressions like `MyInstance[Index]` and delay figuring out what to do until that expression is used.

```
class MyContainer {
private:
    class IndexExpr {
    public:
        // Get data from container:
        operator const Datatype&() const;
        // Expand container if necessary, then store data:
        Datatype& operator=(const Datatype& value);

        // Treat MyInstance[i] = MyInstance[j]; as expected:
        Datatype& operator=(const IndexExpr& rhs)
        { return *this = static_cast<const Datatype&>(rhs); }
    private:
        IndexExpr(MyContainer& cont, unsigned int ind);
        MyContainer& container_;
        unsigned int index_;
        friend class MyContainer;
    };

public:
    IndexExpr operator[](unsigned int Index)
    { return IndexExpr(*this, Index); }

    // No IndexExpr needed when container is const:
    const Datatype& operator[](unsigned int Index) const;

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `operator const Datatype&() const` works?

Comment: @Maxpm: What about it?  It is an implicit conversion operator.  When an expression of type `MyContainer::IndexExpr`, such as `MyInstance[Index]` is used in a context where a `const Datatype&` would make sense, C++ will automatically call that conversion function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect answer to "how to detect", but, if the user is accessing the `operator[]` via a const instance, then throw an exception if the index is out of bounds.
i.e.

```
Datatype const& operator[]() const { .. // don't modify here, throw exception
```

However, if the user is accessing the instance via a non const instance, then by all means expand if the index is out of bounds (and within your acceptable ranges)

```
Datatype& operator[]() { .. // modify here
```

Basically, you are using the const attribute of the instance to determine what your semantics would be (as done in `std::map` - i.e. trying to call `operator[]` on a const instance of a map results in a compiler error - i.e. there is no const qualified `operator[]` for map, because the function is guaranteed to create a mapping if the key does not exist already.)

Comment: This won’t work. `const` isn’t enough to disambiguate between rvalue and lvalue usage.

Comment: -1 This is wrong, the decision on which overload is used depends only on the type of the variable that the operator is applied to, not on what is done with the result. `MyInstance[0]` will call the non-const overload if `MyInstance` is not constant (or a non-const reference), and it will call the `const` version if `MyInstance` is a constant object or a constant reference; regardless of whether the operation appears at the left or right hand side of an assignment.

Comment: @David/@Konrad, I understand that, the point I'm not getting then is, why on earth would you want to expand the array if `MyInstance` is `const`, and if `MyInstance` that is being used is non const, then why isn't it fair game to expand on access? So surely the fact that the user is using either a const/non-const version is guarantee enough as to whether the container should be expanded or not? rather than whether it's rvalue or lvalue?

Comment: @Nim: the rationale you offer is acceptable but the OP wants to have different semantics and his choice can also be justified (like this: reading access shouldn’t modify the object, even if it’s not `const`).